# Boost 1.75 is detected as Boost 1.77 by find_package(Boost) in CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I recently upgraded my Boost installation to Boost 1.75, using the git-repository. Now, when running `find_package(Boost)` it keeps telling me that it found Boost 1.77.0 instead. Is that a bug in CMake or a bug in Boost (or in my own code)?
Full output:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost: Found unsuitable version "1.77.0", but required is
  exact version "1.75" (found /opt/boost/include, found components: system
  filesystem mpi program_options serialization thread chrono date_time
  atomic)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Are you sure that `find_package(Boost)` finds **yours Boost installation**, and not some other one? `find_package` caches its results, so after upgrading Boost you need to clean build directory of your project (or, at least, remove `CMakeCache.txt` file from it). Have you done that?

Comment: I have Boost 1.76 installed locally, and 1.75 in `/opt/`, thus I'm quite sure it does not detect anything else. Moreover, 1.77 has only been tagged on git, but not released yet, and cmake still finds it after deleting CMakeCache and CMakeFiles

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) **exact output** produced by CMake when it processes `find_package(Boost)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Added the output

Comment: Run `cmake` with additional option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`, so it will print more messages about searching Boost. One of these messages should contain location of `version.hpp` header file, which is used by CMake for extract Boost version. Check, that path to that header is *reasonable*. That header file could define version as a value of `BOOST_VERSION` or `BOOST_LIB_VERSION` macro. What is the value of that macro?

Comment: BOOST_VERSION is `107700`, even though all libraries are version 1.75. Will check if a reinstallation fixes the issue.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Reinstallation did not help it appears that even if I check out branch 1.75.0 manually, `version.hpp` is not changed

Comment: @arc_lupus Could you please share which version of CMake you using?

Comment: @SergeiNikulov: Will check, but should be the latest version. Anyway, the issue was with `version.hpp`. It does not change regardless of the checked-out branch number. After editing it manually cmake correctly detects boost 1.75

Comment: Try using the config version of `find_package` to make sure the cmake config files provided by the boost installation are used: `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH <boost install dir>) find_package(Boost 1.75 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... CONFIG)`

Comment: It is not a good idea to use bundled FindBoost.cmake script to find boost package other than the one installed using bundled package manager.